# accuracy in calculation with program

Tags: javascript, python, math

I did a code in python

```
total = 1.56 + 6
print("Total:", total)
```

the result is: Total: 7.5600000000000005

so the result is wrong. while the same calculation run correct in JavaScript

```
<script>
     total  = 1.56 + 6;
     alert(a);
</script>
```

but JavaScript is also inaccuracy with the code below

```
<script>
     a = 7.5600000000000005 * Math.pow(10, 15);
     alert(a);
</script>
```

any one have a solution for it?

Comment: this question gets asked over and over.  floating point numbers are not exact due to the way they work

Comment: Some numbers cant be exactly represented with a limited number of bits. That's why there are packages that are able to calculate exactly, especially for computational geometry. However, that's probably no what you want, so dont worry about such discrepancies, as they can happen.

Comment: I ask for a solution, not why it happen like this. I read through the other question but it's not satisfy. I want to bring it up for some one to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
total  = 1.56 + 6;
console.log(total);
console.log(total*100/100);
```

Try this,
But I don't know why `+` operator is not working as expected

Comment: That's not an answer.